# how to change the main color of iterm2

Tags: terminal, iterm2

I was trying to change the main color of iterm2 using the foreground color, but I discovered that it only affects some text but not all text:
[image]

same goes if I launch mysql on command line, it takes the same color as the command line color.

How do I change those?

### update: the white ansi color is the same as the foreground color:

[image]

I'm using zsh, here is the prompt config in y `.zshrc` file:

```
PROMPT='%F{#9EC084}(${vcs_info_msg_0_})%F{#a0a1a0} %1d %F{#66C2CD}Œª %F{#BCC4CF}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your shell prompt uses a custom color – looks like "ANSI Color 7 (White)" – which is configured separately from the basic foreground.

The prompt also leaves the terminal in an unclean state – instead of resetting the color to "Basic foreground" after the "`λ`", it leaves it set it to "ANSI white", so the same color then continues to be used for command line and even for program output.

When `ls` outputs a colorized filename (such as the `bin`), it *does* issue a reset code, returning text to "Basic foreground" from that point onwards.

Fix your prompt to reset colors using some form of `\e[m` at the end (e.g. `\[\e[m\]` for bash), e.g. at the end of your `PS1` variable. (Alternatively, adjust "ANSI Colors - White" on the right side of the preferences window to match your new foreground color and pretend nothing is wrong.)

Comment: I've already updated the ANSI Colors - White to match the foreground color but no luck. 
I'm using zsh as opposed to bash, I shared my prompt config in the question

Comment: It might also be using colors from the "256 color" cube, which are typically not customizable on most terminals. Again, edit your PS1 to properly reset the formatting at the end – and at the same time, you can adjust it to not set the colors at all if you don't want.

Comment: ah I got it now, so I reset the font after the prompt to the be the same gray color I want like so:
`PROMPT='%F{#9EC084}(${vcs_info_msg_0_})%F{#a0a1a0} %1d %F{#66C2CD}Œª %F{#a0a1a0}'`

Comment: No, you reset it to *default foreground*, not to any specific color at all. I think that's `$reset_color` in zsh.